# C#. Разделить список на интервалы

Tags: c#, список

Есть списки вида:

```
0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 2 2 0 1 1 0 0
```

Необходимо разбить этот список на интервалы, без учета нулей. На выходе массив интервалов состоящий из подряд идущих одинаковых элементов.

Например:

```
[0] = 1, [1] = 1 1 1 1, [2] = 2 2, [3] = 1 1
```

Каким образом это лучше сделать?

Comment: А куда делись у вас пустые интервалы? И что должно получиться из последовательности `1 2 3 0 4`?

Comment: Приношу извинения что не рассмотрел все варианты.Пустых интервалов не должно быть, нули опускаются. Из последовательности 1 2 3 0 4, получаются интервалы [0] = 1, [1] = 2, [2] = 3, [3] = 4. Не знаю как в комментариях код оформлять.. Upd: поправил шапку сообщения.

Comment: В комментариях код будет нечитаемым, добавьте лучше в вопрос (его можно редактировать).

Answer (score 1):

1. Добавим нули к началу и концу списка, чтобы начало и конец были явно
   ограничены.
2. Получим индексы позиций, в которых находятся нули.
3. Получим последовательности, лежащие между нулями.
4. Вернём все не пустые последовательности.
   Примерно так:

   ```
   var baseList=new int[] { 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0 };

   var surrList = new List<int> { 0 };
   surrList.AddRange(baseList);
   surrList.Add(0);
   var zeroindex = surrList.Select((s, i) => new {s, i})
           .Where(x => x.s == 0).Select(x=>x.i).ToArray();
   var result = zeroindex.Select((z, zi) => surrList.ToArray()
           .Where((s, si) =>
                   zi<zeroindex.Length-1 
                   && si>zeroindex[zi] 
                   && si<zeroindex[zi+1]
                 ).ToList())
           .Where(x=>x.Any()).ToList();
   ```

Comment: Спасибо, очень короткое решение. Но я забыл уточнить, что необходимо, что бы интервалы состояли именно из одинаковых идущих друг за другом элементов. В любом случае огромное спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Не такое короткое решение, но за O(n) и без добавления дополнительных маркеров.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var data = new[] { 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0 };

    var result = new List<List<int>>();
    var interval = new List<int>();
    int? previousItem = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
    {
        var item = data[i];
        if (item != 0)
        {
            // если число не совпадает с предыдущим, текущий интервал завершен
            if (previousItem.HasValue && previousItem.Value != item)
            {
                result.Add(interval);
                interval = new List<int>();
            }
            previousItem = item;
            interval.Add(item);
        }
        else
        {
            if (interval.Count > 0)
            {
                // если заполняли интервал, то добавляем его в список результатов
                result.Add(interval);
                interval = new List<int>();
                previousItem = null;
            }
            else
            {
                // иначе переходим к следующему элементу
                continue;
            }
        }
    }

    // исходная последовательность обработана, добавляем последний интервал
    if (interval.Count > 0)
    {
        result.Add(interval);
    }

    foreach (var item in result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", item.ToArray()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но я забыл уточнить, что необходимо, что бы интервалы состояли именно из одинаковых идущих друг за другом элементов... (Шапку вопроса поправил)

Comment: @Nayils исправил.

Comment: @Nayils не за что!

Answer (score 0):

Довольно простой универсальный метод:

```
public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GroupConsecutive<T>(IList<T> items, Predicate<T> filter)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
    {
        if (!filter.Invoke(items[i]))
            continue;

        var current = items[i];
        var result = new List<T>();

        while (items[i].Equals(current))
        {
            result.Add(items[i]);
            i++;
        }

        yield return result;
    }
}
```

Использование:

```
var input = new int[] { 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0 };
var output = GroupConsecutive(input, x => (x != 0)); // {{1}, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 2}, {1, 1}}
```